# Risk neutral measure in exponential levy model

Tags: options, risk-neutral-measure

Is there a method of finding a risk-neutral measure for assets driven by the levy process? I understand there is the esscher transform but I think it tends to transform the processes into unrecognisable/intractable forms. Can anyone provide an explicit method to finding a risk-neutral measure?

Comment: Dont have it handy right now, but have you looked at financial modelling w jump processes, by cont and tankov?